Error el enviar PROPS en React
Tengo este escenario:
Tengo un proyecto de React con varios componentes, al ejecutar un "npm run build" me genera en la carpeta "./dist" un transpilado "index.js".
El archivo transpilado "index.js" lo estoy utilizando en un proyecto que no es de React, en un simple archivo "index.html" con los scripts necesarios:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./js/react-18-3-1.production.min.js?idDeploy=2410241102"></script>
    <script src="./js/react-dom-18-3-1.production.min.js?idDeploy=2410241102"></script>
    <script src="./js/index.js?idDeploy=2410241102"></script><!-- Proyecto transpilado de react -->
    <script>
        //AJUSTES DE ALERTA
            const clTipoAlertaSuccess = "success";
            const msgAlerta = pDescripcionHtml="La libreria funciona de forma correcta."
        //FIN DE AJUSTES DE ALERTA
        
        //AJUSTES DE MAPA
            const vLstMapaConfig = [
                "clMapa":"OSM",
                "lstCoordenadas":"-191.851234, 23.151234"
            ];
            const fNotificarDato = (lstInfoElementoGeografico) => {
                if(lstInfoElementoGeografico){
                    console.log(lstInfoElementoGeografico);
                }
            };
        //FIN DE AJUSTES DE MAPA
        
        const SplMapa = window['spl.components.library'].SplMapa;
        const SplAlerta = window['spl.components.library'].SplAlerta;
        const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(appElement);
        root.render(
           React.createElement(SplAlerta,{ pDsAlerta: msgAlerta, pTipoAlerta: clTipoAlertaSuccess  }),
           React.createElement(SplMapa,{ pLstMapaConfig: JSON.stringify(vLstMapaConfig), pFNotificarDato: fNotificarDato  }),   
            );
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Al abrir ese proyecto "index.html", el componente SplAlerta se genera correctamente, sin embargo el componente SplMapa no se genera, en la consola me genera el siguiente mensaje de error:
ERR01: Los Props pLstMapaConfig y pFNotificarDato no se encuentran definidos.

Los componentes se encuentran definidos de la siguiente forma:

Componente SplAlerta


import React from 'react';
export const SplAlerta = ({pDsAlerta, pTipoAlerta}) => {
    if(!pDsAlerta && !pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR01: Los Props pDsAlerta y pTipoAlerta no se encuentran definidos.");
    } else if(!pDsAlerta && pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR02: El Prop pDsAlerta no se encuentra definido.");
    } else if(pDsAlerta && !pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR03: El Prop pTipoAlerta no se encuentra definido.");
    }
    
};





Componente SplMapa


import React from 'react';
export const SplMapa = ({pDsAlerta, pTipoAlerta}) => {
    if(!pDsAlerta && !pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR01: Los Props pDsAlerta y pTipoAlerta no se encuentran definidos.");
    } else if(!pDsAlerta && pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR02: El Prop pDsAlerta no se encuentra definido.");
    } else if(pDsAlerta && !pTipoAlerta){
        console.log("ERR03: El Prop pTipoAlerta no se encuentra definido.");
    }
    
};




Porque el componente de SplMapa no es capaz de recibir los props y el componente de SplAlerta los recibe sin ningún problema y se renderiza sin ningún error?
Además en otro escenario intente definir los props como variables globales:
window.pLstMapaConfig = vLstMapaConfig;
window.pFNotificarDato = fNotificarDato;

El resultado de utilizarlos de esta forma: Funcionamiento correcto de los componentes.
Porque como props no llegan al componente?

Pero en tu componente SplMapa espera {pDsAlerta, pTipoAlerta} y tu le envias otros nombres. Será eso?
